# Get the empty page count using iText Java

Tags: java, itext

I have 800 pages PDF file, I want to get the count how many pages has been blank, among these 800 pages

Comment: I have a wonderfully simple algorithm to do that, but unfortunately it won't fit in this [margin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)....

Comment: The problem with your question is that blank pages aren't always blank. What may seem blank to the human eye when viewed in a PDF viewer, may not be blank to software reading the syntax in the PDF file. You'll have to specify what you mean by "blank page" and this "definition of a blank page" can differ from file to file.

Comment: Note: I see that the question received 2 downvotes. I wouldn't downvote it, because it's not a bad question, it's just a question that may very well be unanswerable. That doesn't make it an illegitimate question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass it through java.io.RandomAccessFile. It will look similar to this:

```
int efficientPDFPageCount(File file) {
     RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
     RandomAccessFileOrArray pdfFile = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(
          new RandomAccessSourceFactory().createSource(raf));
     PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile, new byte[0]);
     int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
     reader.close();
     return pages;
  }
```

------**EDIT**------

This is not my code, but I found this on how to detect and delete blank pages.

Here is the link: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-detect-and-remove-blank-page-in-pdf.html

Comment: This tells you how many pages there are in the document, not how many of those pages are blank.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not working with Java but in VB.Net, the following code works, I think you just need to get the equivalent methods and convert the code :

```
    Private Sub DeleteEmptyPage()
        Dim lstIdxEmptyPage As New List(Of Integer)

        For iPage As Integer = 1 To _pdf.GetNumberOfPages
            Dim page As PdfPage = _pdf.GetPage(iPage)
            Dim pageContent As Byte() = page.GetContentBytes()

            If pageContent.Length > 0 Then
                Continue For
            Else
                lstIdxEmptyPage.Add(iPage)
            End If
        Next

        For Each idxPage As Integer In lstIdxEmptyPage
            Me._pdf.RemovePage(idxPage)
        Next
    End Sub
```

=> *_pdf* is a *iText.Pdfa.PdfADocument* object
This method will search all pages with empty content (Lenght Bytes = 0). I stored these pages (index) in a list and I will browse this list to remove each page (with it index).

I hope this help.

Comment: this is probably stricter than desired: most likely the op wanted to find pages which *appear* blank. Pages appearing blank may well have a non-empty content stream. E.g. pdf creators often prepare each page by selecting a font or creating a clip path, even pages eventually left blank.